# Element keeps scrolling with page

Tags: css

I created a banner but the item keeps scrolling and sticks on top of the page even when I have put the fixed position. I want to make it to be visible only when you are on top of the page and hide when you scroll down.

I am using

```
position:fixed; bottom: 0; padding:0; margin:0; width: 100%;
```

Comment: What is your html structure? Does your element have parent class?

Comment: Please post you relevant HTML code, and where are you using selectors in css.

Comment: Please share all relevant codes or a working fiddle for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can read up on CSS positions [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Basically `position: fixed` will 'stick' to where the element is first rendered (in your case at the top).

If you want it to act like a normal element change the `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` or `position: static` or just remove the position style entirely.

I hope this awnsers your question!